# Use of full-text search + GIN in a view (Django 1.11 )

Tags: postgresql, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, gwt-gin

I need some help with building proper query in a django view for full-text search using GIN index. I have quite a big database (~400k lines) and need to do a full-text search on 3 fields from it. Tried to use [django docs search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) and this is code BEFORE GIN. It works, but takes 6+ seconds to search over all fields. Next I tried to implement a [GIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/) index to speed up my search. There are a lot of questions already how to build it. But my question is - **how does the view query change when using a GIN index for search?** What fields should I search?


**Before GIN:**

*models.py*

```py
class Product(TimeStampedModel):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    shop = models.ForeignKey("Shop", to_field="shop_name")
    brand = models.ForeignKey("Brand", to_field="brand_name")
    title = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

*views.py*

```py
   
def get_cosmetic(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        pass
    else:
        search_words = request.POST.get("search")
        search_vectors = (
            SearchVector("title", weight="B")
            + SearchVector("description", weight="C")
            + SearchVector("brand__brand_name", weight="A")
        )

        products = (
            Product.objects.annotate(
                search=search_vectors, rank=SearchRank(search_vectors, search)
            )
            .filter(search=search_words)
            .order_by("-rank")
        )

        return render(request, "example.html", {"products": products})
```

**After GIN:**

*models.py*

```py
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def with_documents(self):
        vector = (
            pg_search.SearchVector("brand__brand_name", weight="A")
            + pg_search.SearchVector("title", weight="A")
            + pg_search.SearchVector("description", weight="C")
        )
        return self.get_queryset().annotate(document=vector)


class Product(TimeStampedModel):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    shop = models.ForeignKey("Shop", to_field="shop_name")
    brand = models.ForeignKey("Brand", to_field="brand_name")
    title = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    search_vector = pg_search.SearchVectorField(null=True)

    objects = ProductManager()

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            indexes.GinIndex(
                fields=["search_vector"],
                name="title_index",
            ),
        ]

    # update search_vector every time the entry updates
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if (
            "update_fields" not in kwargs
            or "search_vector" not in kwargs["update_fields"]
        ):
            instance = (
                self._meta.default_manager
                .with_documents().get(pk=self.pk)
            )
            instance.search_vector = instance.document
            instance.save(update_fields=["search_vector"])
```

*views.py*

```py
def get_cosmetic(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        pass

    else:
        search_words = request.POST.get('search')    
        products = ?????????
        return render(request, 'example.html', {"products": products})
```

Comment: Why can't we assign `search_vector` directly to `instance.search_vector`? I cannot understand, pls explain for me. thanks

Comment: @achilles as it is been said in docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save) - `.save(update_fields=['search_vector'])` can update only selected fields and increase the performance. If I correctly understand a question.

Comment: I was asking why we do that
`instance = self._meta.default_manager.with_documents().get(pk=self.pk)
        instance.search_vector = instance.document`
Why can't we assign like that: `instance.search_vector = SearchVector(...)`

Comment: @achilles I think you are right, it can also work (but I am not sure) - the part of this recipe is taken from the link from the answer. May be that simplifies queryset calls by just calling manager method. If you test that - share the results pls, I am curious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```py
products = (
    Product.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(F("search_vector"), search_words))
    .filter(search_vector=search_words)
    .order_by("-rank")
)
```

This means you should search your index field - in my case `search_vector` field.
Also I have changed my code a bit in ProductManager() class, so now I can just use

```
products = Product.objects.with_documents(search_words)
```

Where `with_documents()` is a custom function of custom ProductManager(). The recipe of this change is [here (page 29)](https://ep2017.europython.eu/media/conference/slides/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql.pdf).
*What does all this code do:*

1. creates search_vector with scores to fields, field with bigger score - gets higher place in result sorting.
2. creates GIN index for full-text search via ORM Django
3. updates GIN index every time the instance of model is changed 
   *What this code dosn't do:*
4. It doesn't sort by relevance of substring which is queried. [Possible solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682491/python-how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings-by-substring-relevance)

   Hope this will help somebody with a bit complicated full-text search in Django.

Comment: [here (page 30)](https://www.pycon.it/media/conference/slides/ricerca-full-text-in-django-con-postgresql.pdf) is not working.

Comment: @AnshulTiwari ahh, I checked it a couple of months ago and it was still working :(

Comment: @AnshulTiwari have a look at this presentation - https://ep2017.europython.eu/media/conference/slides/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql.pdf it looks similar to what I based previously (page 29)